# Passing values between pages with Angularjs and Onsen ui v2

Tags: angularjs

I am working on my mobile application using Onsen UI and Angularjs. Everything was good until I started to migrate from Onsen UI v1 to v2. In my case I'm trying to pass data between pages. So, I used $scope.MyNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.Id; in version 1. But now it seems to be changed and the version 2 documentation says to use myNavigator.topPage; 
I did so, but no data was passed between the pages. kindly help me out because I am struggling with this issue for about a week. This is my code:

```
    myApp.controller('CRQDetailsController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.currentCrqStatus = $scope.HomeNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.crqStatus;

        $http.get(BaseServiceURL + "api/Tickets/GetTickets?Token=" + Global_Token + "&Status=" + $scope.currentCrqStatus)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.currentCrqDetails = data;

        }).error(function (err) {
            commonError.show();
        })
    });


    $scope.push = function (Status) {
        $scope.HomeNavigator.pushPage('CRQDetails.html', { crqStatus: Status });
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <ons-list modifier="inset" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="crq in crqs" ng-if="crq.Count>0" ng-click="push(crq.Status)" tappable>
            {{crq.Status}}
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer for my question. Here is the code:

```
    $scope.push = function (Status) {
        HomeNavigator.pushPage("CRQDetails.html", {
            data: {
                crqStatus: Status
            }
        })
        .then(function (page) { //optional
            console.log("Parameter passed: ", page.data)
        })
    }
```

TARGET PAGE: (CRQDetails.html - where the data actually needs to be passed)

```
    // Get the passed parameters
    $scope.currentCrqStatus = HomeNavigator.topPage.data.crqStatus;
```